# C# WPF Application crashes when textboxes are empty

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, field

I have created an application in WPF using C#, in this application the user has to fill in textboxes and calculations are made by clicking a button.
I have already made a failsafe for the part where the textboxes can only be numbers:

```
private bool allFieldsAreOk()
    {
        return this.lengteBox.Text.All(char.IsDigit)
            && breedteBox.Text.All(char.IsDigit)
            && cilinderDrukSterkteBox.Text.All(char.IsDigit)
            && vloeigrensStaalBox.Text.All(char.IsDigit)
            && diameterWapeningBox.Text.All(char.IsDigit)
            && diameterBeugelBox.Text.All(char.IsDigit)
            && betondekkingTotWapeningBox.Text.All(char.IsDigit)
            && vloeigrensConstructieStaalBox.Text.All(char.IsDigit);
    }
```

But whenever a textbox is empty and I press the calculation button, the app crashes. Is there any way to make a failsafe for this too? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Crashes" means that some part of the code produced an exception. If you run your application under the debugger, you will see which exception it is and where exactly it occurs.

Comment: This is the exception's description: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: And BTW: `All(char.IsDigit)` will return `true` for an empty string which might not be what you expect from your code.

Comment: Is there a way to make it return false when an empty string is used?

Comment: Of course, add `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.lengteBox.Text)` etc. conditions.

Comment: Either check `string.Length > 0` or replace your validation with `int.TryParse`/`double.TryParse`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` to check the text instead, and I would separate the fields out into different checks so you know what field is not filled in and you can communicate this to the user;

```
private ICollection<string> CheckFields()
    {
        var ret = new List<string>();

        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lengteBox.Text))
        {
            ret.add($"{nameof(lengteBox)} was null, empty or consisted only of whitespace.");
        }
        else
        {
            // So the string is not null, but here we can also check if the value is a valid digit for example 
            var isNumeric = int.TryParse(lengteBox.Text, out _);
            if(!isNumeric)
                ret.add($"{nameof(lengteBox)} could not be parsed as an interger, value: {lengteBox.Text}.");
        }

        // Add validation to the other boxes etc.


        return ret;
    }
```

then in your 'run calculation' button you can do something like this;

```
var errors = CheckFields();

if(errors.Any())
{

   // show a messagebox, see; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/dialog-boxes-overview
   MessageBox.Show(string.Join(errors, Environment.NewLine));
   return;
}

// Found no errors, run the calcuations here! :D
```

There are likely other ways but this is quick, simple and you can output very verbose errors.